# How can I change /home formatting from XFS to ext4 without loss of data

Tags: filesystems, partition

I have opensuse Leap 15.0, while installing it, I didn't specify the formatting for each partition. Now I want to change my /home partition (I give a separate partition for the home to my data and configuration files) from XFS to ext4.
So is there a way to do that without formatting it ?

Comment: Very unlikely. Backup your data, reformat, and then restore the backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you'll need to copy the data elsewhere, create the `ext4` filesystem and copy the data back.

I think Leap uses `LVM` by default, so you could add an extra disk to the `LVM`, create a new logical volume, create a `ext4` file system and copy the data. You could then remove the `XFS` filesystem and finally remove the additional disk from `LVM`.

In case you don't know, you cannot shrink a `XFS` filesystem, so you can't shrink the current volume to copy to a new `ext4` volume.

Answer (score 0):

we got fstransform

https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform

same tutorials:
https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6134431 [1]
https://fedoramagazine.org/transform-file-systems-in-linux/

[1]
Step 1
Install tool from EPEL repository:

$ sudo yum -y install fstransform

Step 2
Check current setup for file system /myfs:

$ uname -a && sudo lsblk -f | awk '$NF=="/myfs" {print $NF,"is file system type",$2}'
Linux myhost.domain.dom 3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 13 18:55:45 EDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
/myfs is file system type ext4

$ sudo mount | grep myfs
/dev/mapper/myvg-mylv on /myfs type ext4 (rw,noatime,data=ordered)

Step 3
Unmount file system /myfs and run the conversion:

$ sudo umount /myfs

$ sudo fstransform /dev/mapper/myvg-mylv xfs

Step 4
Change file system type in /etc/fstab and remount /myfs:

$ sudo sed -i -e "s#/myfs.*ext4#/myfs xfs#" /etc/fstab

$ sudo mount /myfs

$ uname -a && sudo lsblk -f | awk '$NF=="/myfs" {print $NF,"is file system type",$2}'
Linux myhost.domain.dom 3.10.0-1160.25.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 13 18:55:45 EDT 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
/myfs is file system type xfs